# How can I change the name of libwx_gtk2ud_richtext-2.8

Tags: c++, static-libraries, wxwidgets

I've googled most of answers on this site but none of the answers solved my problem.

I am trying to build a project uses wx libraries. And compiler looks for -`lwx_gtk2ud_richtext-2.8` file.But my `wx-config --libs` command gives `libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8`. How can I change the name to add gtk2ud ,and would it solve my problem ?

Comment: "ud" sounds like a debug version.

Comment: So why ld cant find it ? I have the wx libraries,it only cant found "ud" versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recompile the library.

1. Remove the directory where you build it.
2. Create a directory to build the library.
3. Change to that directory and issue:

   `../configure --enable-unicode --enable-debug`
4. Issue make
5. Compile you project.

BTW, is there a reason you are trying an outdated version of wx?
You should get the latest 3.1 release.

Comment: I am working on an old project and 3.1 causes some errors.

Comment: @UğurKURT, you need to fix those errors and upgrade to 3.1. If you have any issues fixing them, please post to either wx-users ML or to wxWidgets forum. There is no reason whatsoever to work with outdated software and find that there is a bug which may already be fixed in the later version. Also please accept the answer as a solution.